# Group By with multiple Having on the same field

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, having

Example Table:

```
a | b
-----
1 | 1
1 | 2
2 | 1
3 | 0
3 | 1
4 | 1
4 | 2
4 | 3
5 | 0
```

I'd like to get all `DISTINCT` values of column `a`, which are associated with values from column `b`, where `b = 1 AND b = 2`.

The result should be:

```
a
-
1
4
```

Does this work with `GROUP BY`? I tried the following SQL, but it gives always 0 results:

```
SELECT t.a
FROM table t
GROUP BY t.a, t.b
HAVING t.b = 1 AND t.b = 2
```

MySQL seems to call the `AND` statement on the same row and not on the grouped `b` rows.

Any ideas? `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close.  Try this:

```
SELECT t.a
FROM table t
GROUP BY t.a
HAVING SUM(t.b = 1) > 0 AND SUM(t.b = 2) > 0;
```

Each of the `SUM()` conditions counts the number of rows where the condition is true.  You want both, hence the `> 0` and `AND`.

**EDIT** removed `t.b` from `GROUP BY`

Comment: Yeah. sometimes you miss the forest for the trees... Thank you. **EDIT** you've got to remove `t.b` from the `GROUP BY`. afterwards I'll accept this.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is as follows:

```
SELECT t.a
FROM table t
GROUP BY t.a
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN b=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) <> 0
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN b=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) <> 0
```

Note that you need to remove `t.b` from `GROUP BY`, otherwise the results would be incorrect.

[Demo.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39348/1)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT t.a
FROM table t
WHERE (t.b = 1 OR t.b = 2)
GROUP BY t.a
HAVING COUNT(t.a) > 1
```

Comment: Note that this query works only under the assumption that there are no duplicate `(a, b)` tuples in the table. For example, if you add a duplicate `(2, 1)` record to OP's table, `2` would be added to the output as well ([demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/22535/2)).

Comment: Good point! So this answers works only for a data set with `UNIQUE(a, b)` constraint, which is okay regarding the question, but should really have been mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use sub-query like this :

```
select a from t where b=1 and a in (select a from t where b=2);
```